# react-bootstrap NavBar not working as intended

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am fairly new to react and I have this issue with `<NavDropdown.Item>` in the following class:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Nav, Navbar, NavItem, NavDropdown } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { LinkContainer } from 'react-router-bootstrap';
import './NavMenu.css';


export class NavMenu extends Component {
  displayName = NavMenu.name


  render() {
    return (
        <Navbar bg="primary" variant="dark" fluid fixedTop collapseOnSelect>
            <Navbar.Header>
                <Navbar.Brand>
                    Brand
                </Navbar.Brand>
                <Navbar.Toggle />
            </Navbar.Header>
            <Navbar.Collapse>
                <Nav>
                    <LinkContainer to={'/'} exact>
                        <NavItem>
                            Home
                        </NavItem>
                    </LinkContainer>

                    <NavDropdown title="Dropdown" id="collasible-nav-dropdown">
                        <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.1">Action</NavDropdown.Item>
                        <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.2">Another action</NavDropdown.Item>
                    </NavDropdown>
                </Nav>
            </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Navbar>
    );
  }
}
```

Once I build my project the following error shows up:

[image]

Replacing `<NavDropdown.Item>` by `<MenuItem>` works but I am wondering what's the cause of such problem.

Comment: Doesn't seem like you're even importing `NavBardropdown`. You're importing `NavDropdown`

Comment: @codemonkey, the example I saw on the react-bootstrap website uses NavDropdown which is what I'm importing.

Comment: @Costa could you link the example you were following?

Comment: yes of course @theJuls, here it is: [https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navbar/](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navbar/), I took a bit from each code and everything was working well until I got to the dropdown part.

Comment: After a quick look, I'm in agreement with @Sajib Khan, it looks like a version mismatch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are using "react-bootstrap" `0.33.1` version. And "MenuItem" is used in this version so that it works for you, see [here](https://react-bootstrap-v3.netlify.app/components/navbar/)

You could upgrade the version to `v1.4.0` to use "NavDropdown.Item", see [here](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navs/)

Comment: You were right, my code runs now whoever the navbar doesn't look at all how it is supposed to, this might be because of another version mismatch perhaps, I will do my research about that one.